# Finding cos(a-B) using tan a = 4/3 in quad III and cos B = 12/13 in quad IV

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Really stuck with this problem, I need help with this asap.

To find cos(a-B), I'm supposed to use:

tan a = 4/3, with a in quadrant III

cos B = 12/13, with B in quadrant IV

Comment: Do you know that $cos(A-B)=cosAcosB+sinAsinB$?

Comment: Of course, I started by using that formula, but I'm still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

[image: png]

I have shown the relevent identities . I hope this helps answer your question.